# Firebase security rules for Chats / Messages

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Trying to implement some Firebase rules, and for the most part `auth != null` is fine for now, but then we come to stuff like chats and messages and I would like for those to have stricter security rules.

The way that I have the chats saved is the following way: `Chats > MessageId (created by Firebase) > Receiver, Sender, Timestamp, etc.` Not sure how to go about writing the rule especially for the unique `MessageId` which Firebase creates whenever a new chat is created.

Should I be structuring my data differently, or is this an acceptable scenario the way I save the chats to the database?

[image]

What I have tried so far is something like this:

```
"Chats": {
         "$uid1": {
           "$uid2": {
             ".read": "auth.uid == $uid2",
               ".write": "auth.uid == $uid2",
           },
             ".read": "auth.uid == $uid1",
               ".write": "auth.uid == $uid1"
         }
       }
```

,but it doesn't work. For some reason the home screen then just doesn't load...

Can someone share how to implement good security rules for this type of chat I have going on here?

Answer (score 0):

MessageId is created by firebase. Auth-id is your user id. You can't compare the two. You can try this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Chats": {
      "$message_id": {
        // any logged in user can get a list of messages
       ".read": "auth !== null",

        // sender can be write
        ".write": "newData.child('sender').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "Chatslist": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
        ".validate": "root.child('users/'+$user_id).exists()",  
        "$receiver_id": {
           // user must already exist to add a new receiver
          ".write": "root.child('users/'+$receiver_id).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure but you can read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules). There is an example similar this

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the JSON structure. I think the problem could be the Chatlist node, maybe I have to write different Firebase rules for it too, but nothing loads on the Home screen when I change the rules for Chats to the ones above.

Comment: Yes, you have to write rules for all of them. I edited my answer. Could you try this.

Comment: Hey Kasim, just tried it and didn't work. Home screen remains blank when I change the rules to the above ones. I'm going to try to see if I can figure this out using the docs. I think that the problem might be the $messageId, but I'm not sure...

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example

Comment: I edited my answer again. I edited it according to the document.

Comment: Kasim, what's up buddy. I tried like this also, and still doesn't work. Home screen ends up blank when I change the rules from the ones I have now to these. Ones I have now are simply "auth != null"...